# Folium map creation

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I am failing to visualise a map from a dataframe with location data

I have a dataframe created from a json file of foursquare data and i am trying to visualise the extracted locations but I am facing challenges showing the map. Below is the code and the error I am facing

```
soweto_map = folium.Map(location=[soweto_latitude, soweto_longitude], 
zoom_start=11) # generate the Soweto map    

# add Ecco as a red circle mark
    folium.features.CircleMarker(
    [soweto_latitude, soweto_longitude],
    radius=10,
    popup=label,
    fill=True,
    color='red',
    fill_color='red',
    fill_opacity=0.6
    ).add_to(soweto_map)

# add popular spots to the map as blue circle markers
for lat, lng, label in zip(sodataframe.lat, sodataframe.lng, 
sodataframe.categories):
    folium.features.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lng],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        fill=True,
        color='blue',
        fill_color='blue',
        fill_opacity=0.6
        ).add_to(soweto_map)


# display map
soweto_map
```

---

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-148-c40af89cf70e> in <module>
      9     color='red',
     10     fill_color='red',
---> 11     fill_opacity=0.6
     12     ).add_to(soweto_map)
     13 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in 
__init__(self, location, radius, popup, **kw)
    868     """
    869     def __init__(self, location, radius=10, popup=None, **kw):
--> 870         super(CircleMarker, self).__init__(location=location, 
popup=popup)
    871         self._name = 'CircleMarker'
    872         options = _parse_path(**kw)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/map.py in 
__init__(self, location, popup, icon)
    651             self.add_child(Popup(popup))
    652         elif popup is not None:
--> 653             self.add_child(popup)
    654 
    655         self._template = Template(u"""

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/element.py in 
add_child(self, child, name, index)
    106         """Add a child."""
    107         if name is None:
--> 108             name = child.get_name()
    109         if index is None:
    110             self._children[name] = child

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_name'
```

Comment: Hi there, it seems like you could benefit from a process of elimination here. Assuming you're using Jupyter notebooks, could you break up the map creation into a few cells and try 1) creating the base map, 2) adding the red circle marks, and 3) adding the blue circles? Otherwise, I'd suggest adding a minimum replicable example that contains some data so that we can reproduce what you're seeing. My suspicion is that the answer to your problem lies in the contents of `sodataframe`.

Comment: Can you share what version of folium you're using? `print(folium.__version__)` If you're not using 0.10.0 or higher, please update. I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: looks i am using version  0.5.0 thanks for that answer